# oracle collection with pls_integer

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have created package in oracle and have defined type as below

```
TYPE type_<xxx> IS TABLE OF <table>.value%TYPE INDEX BY pls_integer;
```

Now I connect with .NET to oracle and call some method from package on which one of the argument is type_ type. all works fine

But I have another method on package with below script

```
distinctNewValues := pperiods MULTISET except curweekdayarray;
```

where `distinctNewValues` ,`pperiods`  and `curweekdayarray` are `type_<xxx>`  types

And when compiling package it gives error on

```
distinctNewValues := pperiods MULTISET except curweekdayarray;
```

*Error details:*

```
line.

error:Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY <schema>.<pkg_name>

Error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MULTISET_EXCEPT_ALL'
Line: 163
Text: distinctNewValues := pperiods MULTISET except  curweekdayarray;

Error: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line: 163
Text: distinctNewValues := pperiods MULTISET except  curweekdayarray;
```

I can define type without `pls_integer` index. But `.NET` works only with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are facing that error simply because `multiset` operator expects to see nested tables as its operands and you have associative arrays. So, to be able to use `multiset` operator you need nested tables.

This anonymous PL/SQL block will raise `PLS-00306` error:

```
declare
  type t_list is table of number index by pls_integer; -- associative array
  l_col1 t_list;
  l_col2 t_list;
  l_col_res t_list;
begin
  l_col1(1) := 1;
  l_col2(1) := 1;
  l_col_res := l_col1 multiset except l_col2;
end;

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MULTISET_EXCEPT_ALL'
ORA-06550: line 9, column 3:
```

And this one will not(change our associative array to nested table):

```
declare
  type t_list is table of number; -- nested table
  l_col1 t_list := t_list(1,2,3);
  l_col2 t_list := t_list(1,2);
  l_col_res t_list;
begin
  l_col_res := l_col1 multiset except l_col2;
end;


anonymous block completed
```

Comment: i understand. then second question raises. how convert my  type created by pls_integer to simple table type?

Comment: @AEMLoviji Simply leave the `index by pls_integer` clause out.

Comment: at the end of my question i have wrote that I can define type without pls_integer index. But .NET works only with it

Comment: @AEMLoviji Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with .NET, but, first, you definitely cannot use `multiset` operators with associative arrays, and second, [take a look at this document](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featUDTs.htm) and specifically at `Attribute Mappings Between UDTs and Custom Object Types` table.